# Usage of synchronized with ConcurrentHashMap compound operations(contains+get+put)

Tags: java, concurrency

Can you please read through below code and help to let me know if i need to use synchronized keyword with the concurrent hash map in this example?

The main problem is i dont understand when a synchronized keyword needs to be used in compound operations in a concurrent hash map.can someone please help

```
    import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingDeque;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque;

class Pair  { 
    public final Integer x; 
      public final Integer y; 
      public Pair(Integer x, Integer y) { 
        this.x = x; 
        this.y = y; 
      }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((x == null) ? 0 : x.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((y == null) ? 0 : y.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Pair other = (Pair) obj;
        if (x == null) {
            if (other.x != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!x.equals(other.x))
            return false;
        if (y == null) {
            if (other.y != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!y.equals(other.y))
            return false;
        return true;
    }


} 
class Order{
    int clOrdId;
    int origClOrdId;
    String symbol;
    int qty;
    double price;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Order [clOrdId=" + clOrdId + ", origClOrdId=" + origClOrdId + ", symbol=" + symbol + ", qty=" + qty
                + ", price=" + price + ", side=" + side + "]";
    }
    char side;
    Order(int clOrdId,String symbol,int qty,double price,char side){
        this.clOrdId=clOrdId;
        this.symbol=symbol;
        this.qty=qty;
        this.price=price;
        this.side=side;
    }
    Order(int clOrdId,int origClOrdId,String symbol,int qty,double price,char side){
        this.clOrdId=clOrdId;
        this.origClOrdId=origClOrdId;
        this.symbol=symbol;
        this.qty=qty;
        this.price=price;
        this.side=side;
    }
}
class Message {
    int sessionId;
    Order order;
    Message(int sessionId, Order order) {
        this.sessionId = sessionId;
        this.order = order;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Message [sessionId=" + sessionId + ", order=" + order + "]";
    }
}

/*
 * Different clients can submit different messages 1. Each message has a
 * sessionId and a string msg 2. Each of the messages on a particular session
 * need to be processed sequentially
 */
public class Concurrency {
    private Map<Integer, BlockingDeque<Runnable>> pendingTasks = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private Map<Pair,Order> orderMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(13);
    public void submitMsg(final Message msg) {
        submitTask(msg, () -> {
            if(msg.order.origClOrdId==0){
                print("Received new order msg " + msg);
                sleep(1000);
            }else{
                Pair key = new Pair(msg.sessionId,msg.order.origClOrdId);
                if(orderMap.containsKey(key)){
                    if(isOnlyAggressivePriceMod(msg, key) ){
                        print("Aggressive price modification "+ msg);
                    }else if(isOnlyQtyModUp(msg, key)){
                        print("          Quantity modification up only for "+ msg);
                    }else if(isOnlyQtyDown(msg, key)){
                        print("                     Quantity modification down only for "+ msg);
                    }

                }
            }
            orderMap.put(new Pair(msg.sessionId,msg.order.clOrdId), msg.order); 
        });
    }

    private boolean isOnlyQtyDown(final Message msg, Pair key) {
        return msg.order.qty<orderMap.get(key).qty && Double.compare(msg.order.price,orderMap.get(key).price)==0;
    }

    private boolean isOnlyQtyModUp(final Message msg, Pair key) {
        return msg.order.qty>orderMap.get(key).qty && Double.compare(msg.order.price,orderMap.get(key).price)==0;
    }

    private boolean isOnlyAggressivePriceMod(final Message msg, Pair key) {
        return ((Double.compare(msg.order.price,orderMap.get(key).price)>0 && msg.order.side=='B') || 
           (Double.compare(msg.order.price,orderMap.get(key).price)<0 && msg.order.side=='S')) && Double.compare(msg.order.qty,orderMap.get(key).qty)==0;
    }

    private void sleep(int time){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(time);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void print(String msg){
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
    private void submitTask(final Message msg, Runnable task) {
        synchronized(pendingTasks){
            if (pendingTasks.containsKey(msg.sessionId)) {
                pendingTasks.get(msg.sessionId).add(task);
                return;
            }
        }
        BlockingDeque<Runnable> pendingTasksPerSession = new LinkedBlockingDeque<Runnable>();
        pendingTasksPerSession.push(task);
        pendingTasks.put(msg.sessionId, pendingTasksPerSession);
        executorService.submit(new SynchronizedTask(msg, task));
    }

    public class SynchronizedTask implements Runnable {
        Message msg;
        Runnable task;

        public SynchronizedTask(Message msg, Runnable task) {
            this.msg = msg;
            this.task = task;
        }

        public void run() {
            task.run();
            BlockingDeque<Runnable> pendingTasksForSession = pendingTasks.get(msg.sessionId);
            if (!pendingTasksForSession.remove(task)) {
                return;
            }
            if (!pendingTasksForSession.isEmpty())
                executorService.submit(new SynchronizedTask(msg, pendingTasksForSession.getFirst()));       
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Concurrency c = new Concurrency();
        for(int i =1;i<10;i++){
            c.submitMsg(new Message(i, new Order(10,"0001.HK",2000*i,200+i,'B')));
            c.submitMsg(new Message(i, new Order(11,10,"0001.HK",1000*i,200+i,'B')));
            c.submitMsg(new Message(i, new Order(12,11,"0001.HK",2000*i,201+i,'B')));
        }
        for(int i =1;i<10;i++){
            c.submitMsg(new Message(i, new Order(10,"0001.HK",2000*i,200+i,'S')));
            c.submitMsg(new Message(i, new Order(11,10,"0001.HK",1000*i,200+i,'S')));
            c.submitMsg(new Message(i, new Order(12,11,"0001.HK",2000*i,201+i,'S')));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: you should really define the *exact* problem you have as right now you are asking for someone to look at the entire code and analyze it... that probably belongs to codereview.